# mysql creates two exact rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've an web application with Laravel 7.2.5 ( PHP 7.2 ) and MySQL 5.7
; regularly when a user clicks on a link , a record will be inserted into DB , but at some cases after click , two exact rows will be inserted :

[image: i.e.]

by refer to *created_at* and *updated_at* it seems impossible that user clicked twice immediately. any idea what's the reason and how to prevent it ?

Comment: use javascript to prevent twice click

Comment: Actually , the mentioned link in not available on a html page . I send link to users by SMS

Comment: Then make your mysql field unique, to prevent duplicate row

Comment: *by refer to created_at and updated_at it seems impossible that user clicked twice immediately* Why? I do not see any reason for this conclusion. On the contrary, rattling of mouse contacts may produce such effect, for example. I agree with @sta - unique index by proper expression must solve by preventing such duplication.

Comment: You can prevent this behaviour using unique index with your DB table

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in the comments, the link is sent through SMS - text message.

If you want to prevent double tap on the link (which is defininetly possible in the same second), you'll have to implement some kind of server side validation.

For instance, you could keep track of SMS you send and allow only one "activation", so the double tap would result in a `403 Forbidden`.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the link with the use of onclick event so that one can't click on the same link twice :

`<a id="submitlink" onclick="document.getElementById('submitlink').disabled = true;">Click Me</a>`